# Materialize modal back to top button

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I have a modal from Materialize, I want to make the modal back to top when user close the modal.

Modal Image:

[image: Modal Image]

I try to get the scroll value like:

```
console.log("Scroll Top: " + modalContent.scrollTop);
console.log("Offset: " + modalContent.offsetTop);
```

The console:

```
Scroll Top: 229
Offset: 0
```

I thought That I can override the scrollTop value, but when I do like:

```
document.querySelector(".modal-content").scrollTop = 0;
```

Nothing happen to the modal (the modal not scrolling to the top).

When I try to log the current position with:

```
console.log(document.querySelector(".modal-content").scrollTop)
```

It always returns zero whenever I scrolled trought the modal.
I want that when user click close the modal is scrolled back to the top. Did I miss something?

Modal:

```
<div id="team-modal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer margin-top-50">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="card-panel teal modal-scroll">
      <h4 class="white-text light center modal-mark">Team Detail</h4>
      <hr>
      <div class="center">
        <img class="modal-flag-image" src="./assets/images/not-found.svg" alt="Country Flag">
      </div> <!-- center -->
      <div class="center">
        <!-- Some long content here -->
      </div> <!-- center -->
    </div> <!-- card-panel teal-->
  </div> <!-- modal-content -->
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo accent-4">Save Team</a>
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red close-modal-btn">Close</a>
  </div> <!-- modal-footer -->
  </div> <!-- modal modal-fixed-footer -->
```

Close button event listener:

```
let modalClose = document.querySelector(".close-modal-btn");
modalClose.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector(".modal-content").scrollTop = 0;
});
```

Comment: Have you tried Jquery?  $(".modal-content").animate({  scrollTop: "0px" }, 300);

Comment: @Uuuuuumm Haven't try it, I feel like I can finish this just with vanilla..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem, worked for me with:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('scrollTo');

element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Way 1. If you are used materializecss with vanilla Js:

```
const scrollDemo = document.querySelector("#modal1");
scrollDemo.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
console.log('Scroll Top:', scrollDemo.scrollTop);
console.log('Scroll Left:', scrollDemo.scrollLeft);
}, { passive: true });

scrollDemo.scrollTop = 0;
```

Way 2. If you are used vuejs with materializecss then:

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal" @click="openModal">
   .....
</div>


//In Vue put
Vue({
  methods: {
    scrollUp() {
      console.log('Hello I´m  the  onOpenEnd callback :)');
      let content = document.getElementById("modal1")
                   .getElementsByClassName("modal-content")[0];
      content.scrollTop = 0;
     },
     openModal(){
      //Use callback options modal
      let elem = document.querySelector('#modal1');
      var instance = M.Modal.init(elem,{ onOpenEnd: this.scrollUp });
      instance.open();
    }

  }
});
```